# Can a file extension be spoofed in windows?

Tags: windows, file-types

For example, can an .exe file be spoofed in .txt or .mp3 in Windows and still be executed as an executable?

I know some basic methods like:

- using right-to-left override character (U+202E)
- winrar 4 zip file exploit (no longer working)

Is there another new method of doing it in a recent version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do so would be to have a file evil.txt.exe. The user may think its a txt file and double click it which will cause it to execute.

Two things to note here here:

1. The file icon will not look like txt
2. Your windows operating systems settings should be such that it hides the extensions for known files.

Edit: As Suggested by usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ: "If you compile the exe and embed the default txt icon then 90% of the user will really think it's a txt"

Comment: 1 - You can set the icon for the exe to be whatever you want. The default `txt` icon for Windows can be extracted and used, and it will look exact like a text file.

Comment: @termcap This trick can be easily noticed if the user activate the option "see file extension" which most users have done, plus windows file manager show the file description as an executable. But anyways thanks for your answer